# Compiling Spark within Docker results in java.net.SocketException

Tags: maven, apache-spark, docker, socketexception

I am compiling Spark within Docker (`docker build`). At some point, the compilation process gets stuck:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spark Project Tools 2.3.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/clapper/classutil_2.11/1.1.2/classutil_2.11-1.1.2.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/clapper/classutil_2.11/1.1.2/classutil_2.11-1.1.2.pom (3 KB at 166.7 KB/sec)
....
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.1/asm-5.1.jar (53 KB at 1087.8 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.1/asm-commons-5.1.jar (47 KB at 1047.5 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/clapper/grizzled-scala_2.11/4.2.0/grizzled-scala_2.11-4.2.0.jar (626 KB at 6581.1 KB/sec)
Mar 16, 2018 2:28:28 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection timed out (Read failed)
Mar 16, 2018 2:28:28 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
```

Apparently, this doesn't seem to be a network problem, as downloads succeeded just before. Also, when I repeat the build process, it will fail at the same point.

I am running out of ideas of what could be the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Occasionally, it happens that the build process will eventually (after several minutes) download one additional dependency. But this is not acceptable:

```
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.1/asm-tree-5.1.jar (29 KB at 0.0 KB/sec)
```

Comment: did you find a way to fix the issue? I am stuck with the same problem. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the problem is not related to Docker, build the image using host network mode:

```
docker build --network=host ...
```

This will make the container use the network stack of the host when building.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. I presume this implies that this is not a problem related to the Docker networking.

Comment: @Florian Most likely this is not caused by docker. Which maven version or image are you using? Is `IPv6` enabled for docker?

Comment: Using Maven 3.3.9, Java 1.8.0_151 on an Ubuntu 16.04 image. IPv6 is disabled for Docker (I am using the standard configuration. I have not disabled IPv6 and I do not see anything related within the image)